# Что необходимо установить на компьютер, для того, чтобы SqlClient на EntityFramework работал?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework

Создал программу, которая использует EntityFramework версии 6.4.4.
На моем компьютере все работает правильно. Но на другом компьютере программа не работает. Там нет SQL сервера и компьютер в принципе новый, т.е. там нет ничего (но программы на net framework/core запускаются нормально).

Что нужно установить на другом компьютере, чтобы все заработало?
Пробовали установить MS SQL Server Compact, MS SQL Server 2016/2019 LocalDB (устанавливал не сам, но сказали, чт оустановили) - но не помогло.

DataContext в конструкторе устанавливает инициализатор "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" (ошибка не в миграциях и т.п.).

Если дебажить, то ошибка такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На компьютере клиента не должно чего-либо стоять, ведь база - это сервер, некое единое устройство с открытым доступом и установленным софтом (SQL Server), к которому подключаются клиенты. Если у вас каждый клиент будет ставить свой сервер, то он не увидит данные, которые были добавлены другим участником (сервер другой), да и какой смысл в SQL Server? Переносите тогда проект на SQLite, LiteDB и др., будет у вас рядом с проектом файлик, который уникален для каждого клиента.

Comment: Вам надо не установкой чего попало заниматься, а прописать правильную строку подключения в конфиге и проверить что нужные порты открыты в брандмауэре.